# Radius ratio of capped octahedral coordination (CN=7)

Tags: molecular-structure, crystal-structure

I was asked to work out the Radius ratio of capped octahedral coordination when CN = 7. How to define a capped octahedral? Is there any restrictions on the lengths of the edges or the distances of the vertex to the center?

Comment: Actually, that link isn't helpful for working out the ratio at all. See [this publication by Roald Hoffman](http://www.roaldhoffmann.com/sites/all/files/116s_0.pdf) instead.

Comment: tks,man. I will use Mathematica to have a calculation.